# ValueError: X has 292 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 305 features as input

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i am trying to run some code for a ML competition, but i am facing an error while predicting on new data which i have been unable to fix by looking at other posts.
Her is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor


PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "kagglecompetition"
IMAGES_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID)
os.makedirs(IMAGES_PATH, exist_ok=True)

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True, fig_extension="png", resolution=300):
    path = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, fig_id + "." + fig_extension)
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path, format=fig_extension, dpi=resolution)


housing = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
print(housing.info())
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

'''NULL CATEGORIES - LotFrontage - 1201, Alley - 91, MasVnrType, MasVnrArea - 1452, BsmtQual       1423 non-null   object
 31  BsmtCond       1423 non-null   object
 32  BsmtExposure   1422 non-null   object
 33  BsmtFinType1   1423
 BsmtFinType2   1422
 Electrical     1459
 FireplaceQu    770
 GarageType     1379 non-null   object
 59  GarageYrBlt    1379 non-null   float64
 60  GarageFinish   1379
 GarageQual     1379 non-null   object
 64  GarageCond     1379
 PoolQC         7 non-null      object
 73  Fence          281 non-null    object
 74  MiscFeature    54 non-null 
 '''
housing=housing.drop('Id', axis=1)
test=test.drop('Id', axis=1)
y_labels = housing["SalePrice"]



categorical_features=housing.select_dtypes('O').columns.to_list()
print(categorical_features)
numerical_features=housing.drop(categorical_features, axis = 1)

categorical_features_test=test.select_dtypes('O').columns.to_list()

numerical_features_test = test.drop(categorical_features, axis = 1)
'''imputer.fit(numerical_features)
housing = imputer.transform(numerical_features)
housing_tr = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=numerical_features.columns,
index=housing_num.index)
'''


col_to_del=[]
for c in housing.columns:
    if c in categorical_features:
      if (housing[c].isna().sum()/len(housing[c]))>0.3:
            col_to_del.append(c)
      else:
          for a in range(0, len(categorical_features)):

              housing.dropna(subset = [categorical_features[a]])
              test.dropna(subset = [categorical_features_test[a]])
              '''y_train.dropna()
              X_test.dropna(subset = [categorical_features[a]])'''

   




housing.drop(col_to_del, axis=1)
test.drop(col_to_del, axis = 1)
#y_train.drop(col_to_del)
#X_test.drop(col_to_del, axis=1)

'''
cat_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
for x in range(1, len(categorical_features)):
    housing_cat_1hot = cat_encoder.fit_transform(categorical_features)
'''
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
 ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
 
 ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
 ])

num_attribs = list(numerical_features)

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
 ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
 ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), categorical_features),
 ])



num_pipeline_test = Pipeline([
 ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
 
 ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
 ])

num_attribs_test = list(numerical_features_test)

full_pipeline_test = ColumnTransformer([
 ("num", num_pipeline_test, num_attribs_test),
 ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), categorical_features_test),
 ])


housing = full_pipeline.fit_transform(housing)
test = full_pipeline_test.fit_transform(test)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(housing, y_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print(housing)
print(test)

lr_clf = LinearRegression()
lr_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
housing_predictions = lr_clf.predict(X_test)
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(housing_predictions, y_test)
print(np.sqrt(lin_mse))
housing_predictions_train = lr_clf.predict(X_train)
train_mse = mean_squared_error(housing_predictions_train, y_train)
print(np.sqrt(train_mse))

test_preds = lr_clf.predict(test)
'''
lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse)
testscore = lr_clf.score()

print(lin_rmse)
print(testscore)
'''
output = pd.DataFrame({'Id': test.Id,
                       'SalePrice': test_preds})
output.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
```

I've checked all the data preprocessing a lot of times but can't figure out the error.
This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Rishi Mody\kagtrial.py", line 146, in <module>
    test_preds = lr_clf.predict(test)
  File "C:\Users\Rishi Mody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 362, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Users\Rishi Mody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 345, in _decision_function
    X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse=["csr", "csc", "coo"], reset=False)
  File "C:\Users\Rishi Mody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 580, in _validate_data
    self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
  File "C:\Users\Rishi Mody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 395, in _check_n_features
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: X has 292 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 305 features as input.
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you share any link to the dataset? BTW, the error is clear, check your shapes.

Comment: You're running different one hot encoders on your train and test. Now they don't have the same features.

Comment: test_preds = lr_clf.predict(test) . I think you should replace this with test_preds = lr_clf.predict(X_test)

Comment: I tried using the same one hot encoder but the columns used are different

Comment: @CJR any advice on what I should do?

Comment: `test = full_pipeline.transform(test)` use this instead of creating a second pipeline for your test data